# режим privileged в kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Создал на докере version `1.12.3` образ, куда пробрасываю посредствои `usbip` юсбишку. Снаружи убунта `14.04` и внутри та же.В чистом Docker выполнение команды `usbip attach -h 10.0.1.7 -b 2-2` происходит без ошибок

строка запуска образа

```
docker run --name $container_name --net=my_net --ip=10.0.1.5  -ti --privileged -it -v /dev:/dev -v /lib/modules:/lib/modules $container_name
```

пытаюсь сделать деплой этого образа на кубик.
Docker version 17.03.2-ce
kubernetes 1.10, кубик на убунте 14,04

```
spec:
  serviceName: srv
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sp
      image: DockerRegistry:5000/sp:v2
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      ports:
    - containerPort: 222
    volumeMounts:
    - name: dev
      mountPath: /dev
    - name: lib-modeles
      mountPath: /lib/modules
  volumes:
    - name: lib-modeles
      hostPath:
        path: /lib/modules
    - name: dev
      hostPath:
        path: /dev
```

При выполнении `usbip attach -h 10.0.1.7 -b 2-2` выдаёт:

> usbip: error: import device
>   usbip: error: query

судя по многочисленным заметкам на лицо не хватка прав, но выполняется это под рутом (через принудительное `sudo` тоже) и контейнер в привилегированном режиме...